# Apple password Stopped

Tags: password

My apple password quit working.  I can't download apps or buy games.  This just happened a few hours ago.  Where do I go to get this corrected?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions in [this Apple link](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201487).

In summary:

1. Go to [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com),
2. Select how you want to reset your password,
3. Wait for the notification,
4. Follow the onscreen instructions.